# Optaplanner unable to solve one hard constraint

Tags: java, optimization, scheduler, optaplanner

I am currently trying to optimize a Job Shop scheduling algo using optaplanner. However there is one constraint which gets stuck. What all potential steps should I take to try solving this problem.
My Configuration file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver xmlns="https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/solver"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/solver https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/solver/solver.xsd">
  <!--  <environmentMode>FULL_ASSERT</environmentMode>-->
  <environmentMode>NON_REPRODUCIBLE</environmentMode>
  <moveThreadCount>AUTO</moveThreadCount>
  <solutionClass>com.greyorange.taskscheduler.domain.CandidateSolution</solutionClass>
  <entityClass>com.greyorange.taskscheduler.domain.CandidateAssignment</entityClass>

  <scoreDirectorFactory>
    <constraintProviderClass>com.greyorange.taskscheduler.costs.ObjectiveFunction</constraintProviderClass>
    <constraintStreamImplType>BAVET</constraintStreamImplType>
  </scoreDirectorFactory>

  <localSearch>
    <termination>
      <secondsSpentLimit>15</secondsSpentLimit>
    </termination>
    <acceptor>
      <entityTabuSize>7</entityTabuSize>
    </acceptor>
    <forager>
      <acceptedCountLimit>1000</acceptedCountLimit>
      <finalistPodiumType>STRATEGIC_OSCILLATION</finalistPodiumType>
    </forager>
  </localSearch>
  <localSearch>
    <termination>
      <secondsSpentLimit>10</secondsSpentLimit>
    </termination>
    <acceptor>
      <greatDelugeWaterLevelIncrementRatio>0.000001</greatDelugeWaterLevelIncrementRatio>
    </acceptor>
    <forager>
      <acceptedCountLimit>4</acceptedCountLimit>
    </forager>
  </localSearch>
  <localSearch>
    <termination>
      <secondsSpentLimit>2</secondsSpentLimit>
    </termination>
    <localSearchType>HILL_CLIMBING</localSearchType>
    <moveListFactory>
      <moveListFactoryClass>com.greyorange.taskscheduler.neighborhood.SlideTimeWindowMoveFactory
      </moveListFactoryClass>
    </moveListFactory>
  </localSearch>
</solver>
```

I am currently curious to know what all steps I can take. I tried changing the accepted count limits and it solved my problem but my Technical Lead doesnt feel convinced with the solution.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your solver configuration looks heavily fine-tuned, and I wonder if that is really beneficial. Unless you've done some extensive benchmarking on that particular data set, this level of involvement with the solver's business could be counter-productive.

Another thing I noticed is that you're not really giving any of the local searches much time to actually get some real work done. This could be perfectly fine, but as the data set size grows, seconds are no longer enough to get decent results.

Finally, since you're using Bavet, you may be interested in knowing that the version of BAVET that is available in OptaPlanner actually has some serious bugs which [Timefold Solver](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver) resolved after [the fork](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork). ([Case in point](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/commit/0b47ed1ec6332bcbd1ef91075326304deb7bc61b), which required us to very nearly rewrite Bavet from scratch.)

Are these tips going to help you? I have no way of knowing; figuring out why the solver hasn't identified any particular solution requires deep understanding of the problem at hand, which I do not and can not have.